# Positioning and Floating aren't working?

Tags: html, css

I've tried numerous of things to fix this. I cannot seem to get the nested div inside the parent div without having to use margin. I'm trying to get it in the regular way which is `position:relative` on parent and `position:absolute` on nested. It's not working though, anybody know why?

**HTML**

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="logo">
        <img src="/images/logo.png" width="96" height="82">
    </div> 
    <div id="nav">
        <a href="$HOME_PAGE_LINK$">Portfolio</a>
        <a href="#">About</a>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </div>
    <div id="headerPro">
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.header {
    position:relative;
    background-color: #2C2E31;
    border-bottom: #242426 2px solid;
    height: 182px;
}
.logo {
    text-align: center; 
    padding-top: 35px;
}
#nav {
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align:center; 
    text-decoration:none; 
    font-size:20px;
    font-family:raleway-regular; 
}
#nav a {
    border-bottom:#FFFFFF 2px solid; 
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-decoration:none; 
    margin-left: 8px; 
    margin-right:8px;
}
#headerPro {
    position:absolute;
    float:right;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: Have you cleared any floats that may be on the page?

Comment: I'm just now kind of learning how to use position and floating elements... What would clearing the floats do?

Comment: Absolute positioning and floating don't usually go together.

Comment: Well, first lesson: `position: absolute` and `float: /* anything other than 'none' */` makes not much sense.

Comment: second lesson: use a list (`ul`) for you nav, and instead of `float:right`, just use `right:0;`

Comment: So how would I get it to the far right at the same time nesting it with the position element? I'm looking stuff up on this as you guys are replying. So I'm trying.

Comment: I'd suggest using something like `right: 0`.

Comment: I wouldn't use positioning for what you are trying to achieve.  It seems to be not needed.  If you want the nav labels to be right aligned then use display: inline-block; instead of floats and then just text-align: right;

Comment: A relative positioned element is positioned relative to its normal position, not relative to its parent's position

Comment: @Zevoxa [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/PuJH9/) is this you are trying to acheive?

Comment: Never mind, the answer that I pick, for some reason, will not work with me. This is what I'm trying to achieve: http://i.imgur.com/WM3fb68.png

Comment: @Zevoxa, updated my answer, maybe this does the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell what exactly you want it to look like, but maybe I got you right:

I revised your HTML code to use `ul` for the nav which is best practice:

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="logo">
        <img src="/images/logo.png" alt="logo"/>
    </div> 
    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="$HOME_PAGE_LINK$">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="headerPro">
    </div>
</div>
```

With that your css code could look like that:

```
.logo > img {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 96px;
    height: 82px;
}

#nav {
    position:absolute;
    list-style-type: none;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align:center; 
    text-decoration:none; 
    font-size:20px;
    font-family:raleway-regular; 
}

#nav > li {
    display: inline;
}

#headerPro {
    position:absolute;
    top: 35px; /* assuming you want this to line up with the logo */
    right: 0;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:red;
}
```

[Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ukDhW/).

Comment: Possibly bottom: 0; to bring the red box up into it's containing div. Forked from your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VsQZN/1/

Comment: @Zevoxa, You're welcome. One more thing: I forgot the `<li/>`s in the original version which is invalid. Please use the updated code.

Answer (score 1):

See this fiddle

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/58mVD/)

I have made two changes added a float:left to the logo css:

```
.logo {
   float:left;
}
```

and removed the position:absolute from the header pro css

Your div is flowing outside the header block because of the logo div, if you make that float left (as I have done in the fiddle) the Red Div will move up.

It would help if you could explain exactly where you want the #HeaderPro div..

Comment: I want it in the middle of the header about margin-left:50px; but I have a problem. How would I vertically center it?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the browser positions your div#headerPro just below the previous(sibling) div. If you want it to be part of the parent div, add top:2% to position the red div in the top right corner of the black div.

```
#headerPro {
 position:absolute;
 float:right;
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 background-color:red;
 top: 1%;
}
```